# fastapi, celery, redis, docker compose: Endless loop in terminal

Tags: docker-compose, redis, celery, fastapi

I use fastapi, celery, redis and docker-compose to host a REST API. Everything works well except when I trigger a test of the api through the docker compose yaml file.

I want to run everything as a microservice on Microsoft Azure, for example. To do this, the tests should be executed automatically when the containers are started up. Previously, I did this without docker-compose, celery and redis, i.e. only with the Dockerfile and fastapi. That worked without any problems.

Problem: The test starts but then in the linux terminal it prints "api_test_1   | /audio/upload" in an endless loop.

My docker compose yaml:

```
# docker compose file version
# It is a docker intrinsic number
# not your version number.
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        # Host Port:Container Port
      - 8004:8000
    command: uvicorn app.upload_file:app --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/api_code
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis

  
  worker:
    build: .
    command: celery --app=celery_task_app.worker.celery_app worker --loglevel=info --logfile=logs/celery.log
    volumes:
      - .:/api_code
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis

  
  redis:
    image: redis:7


  dashboard:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery --broker=redis://redis:6379/0 flower --port=5555
    ports:
      - 5556:5555
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - worker

api_test:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c 'export BACKEND_URL='http://localhost:8004' && python3 -m tests.api_tests'
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - worker
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Start from the official Python base image.

FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /api_code

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /api_code/requirements.txt


# Install the package dependencies in the requirements file.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /api_code/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg


# torch
#RUN pip install torch==1.13.0+cpu torchvision==0.14.0+cpu torchaudio==0.13.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
RUN pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu


# whisper X
RUN pip install git+https://github.com/m-bain/whisperx.git

COPY ./app /api_code/app

COPY ./tests /api_code/tests

COPY ./logs /api_code/logs

COPY ./celery_task_app /api_code/celery_task_app
```

My api_tests.py file:

```
import unittest

import os

from time import sleep

from jiwer import wer as jiwer_wer

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


from tests.tools_for_tests import calculate_wer

from app.upload_file import app


print('///////////// API Tests Started /////////////')

BACKEND_URL = str(os.environ["BACKEND_URL"])

class TestUpload(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_upload(self):

            print('\n----> Test upload.')

            file_name = "you-call-that-fun.wav"

            # Space at the beginning is no error.
            test_text = ' Fun! You call that fun? That was boring!'

            
            file_to_upload = open(os.path.join('tests', file_name), 'rb')
            files = {'in_file': file_to_upload}
            

            with TestClient(app) as client:
                response = client.post(BACKEND_URL + '/audio/upload',
                                        files=files)
                
                upload_response = response.json()
                task_id = upload_response['task_id']
                assert task_id

                task_response = client.get(BACKEND_URL + f'/audio/result/{task_id}')

                content = task_response.json()

                assert content == {'task_id': str(task_id), 'status': 'Processing'}

                assert response.status_code == 202

                while content['status']== 'Processing':
                     
                    task_response = client.get(BACKEND_URL + f'/audio/result/{task_id}')
                    content = response.json()

                assert content['task_id'] == task_id
                assert content['status'] == 'Success'
    
            # remove the test file
            base_dir = "/api_code/app/data/"
            os.unlink(os.path.join(base_dir, file_name))
            file_to_upload.close()
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My upload.py file which contains the code for the API:**

```
# fastapi
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, HTTPException, status, File
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

import shutil
import os
import time
from filetype import guess

# audio file: MP3 is not supported natively (nor OGG, FLAC, ...).
import sndhdr

from celery_task_app.tasks import predict_whisp_single
from celery.result import AsyncResult

from .tools import check_audio_file


# audio file meta informations
AUDIO_META = ['filetype',
              'sampling_rate',
              'nchannels',
              'nframes',
              'bits_per_sample']


app = FastAPI( title="Upload Audio Files",
    description="API to upload as well as check audio files and use whisperx.",
    version="1.0")

@app.post('/audio/upload',
          status_code=202,
          summary="Upload and process audio file.",
          description="One can upload an wav-file which will be processed by whisperx.",\
          responses={202: {'description': 'Accepted: Not Ready!'}})
async def upload(in_file: UploadFile= File(...)):

    start_time = time.time()

    print('\n##### Run upload and process file #####\n')
    
    try:
        # Current path: /app
        out_file_path = os.path.join("app/data/", f"{in_file.filename}")

        with open(out_file_path, "wb") as buffer_path:
            # copy the contents of a file-like object
            # to another file-like object
            # Here: Copies uploaded file to buffer_path
            shutil.copyfileobj(in_file.file, buffer_path)
        
        print("\tThe file has been read in and is now being processed.")

    except Exception:

        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail=f"There was an error uploading the file: {os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())}"
                
        )          
    
    finally:
        in_file.file.close()

    task_id = check_audio_file(out_file_path, AUDIO_META)

    task_id = predict_whisp_single.delay(str(out_file_path))
    
    del in_file

    print("\n--- Runtime upload: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    print("#################################################################")

    return {'task_id': str(task_id), 'status': 'Processing'}    
    

@app.get('/audio/result/{task_id}', status_code=202,\
         responses={202: {'description': 'Accepted: Not Ready!'},\
                    200: {'description': 'Processed and ready.'}})
async def audio_result(task_id):

    """Fetch result for given task_id"""

    task = AsyncResult(task_id)

    if not task.ready():
        print(app.url_path_for('upload'))
        return JSONResponse(status_code=202,\
                            content={'task_id': str(task_id), 'status': 'Processing'})
       
    result = task.get()

    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,\
                        content={'task_id': task_id, 'status': 'Success', 'prediction': result})


# Show image on frontend.
app.mount("/app", StaticFiles(directory="app"), name='images')
 
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse, status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def serve():
    return """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <img src="/app/logo.webp">
        <h1>Welcome to the API</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
```

I searched a lot in the web: No solution.
The problem is based on a hint by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77782209/edit).

I have found out via the log file that the job is being processed in the background and as long as this is happening, the above message is displayed - again and again - in the terminal: api_test_1   | /audio/upload. Unfortunately, you cannot see when the process was completed.